# Suggest a way in threading that always fixed number of threads must be used in computing?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have an array of filepath in `List<string>` with thousands of files. I want to process them in a function parallel with 8 threads.

```
ParallelOptions opt= new ParallelOptions();
opt.TaskScheduler = null;
opt.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8;
Parallel.ForEach(fileList, opt, item => DoSomething(item));
```

This code works fine for me but it guarantees to run max 8 threads and I want to run 8 threads always. CLR decides the number of threads to be use as per CPU load.

Please suggest a way in threading that always 8 threads are used in computing with minimum overhead.

Comment: How about using `Task.Run` of 1/8 of the files? It should run on ThreadPool threads and if the pool has 8 available threads, they should run together.

Comment: This may not be relevant to ask, but is there a specific reason you need 8 threads and don't want the framework to handle it for you?

Comment: I think david is right, but if you insist. why not just create 8 threads?

Comment: I have noticed a very strange behaviour of MaxDegreeOfParallelism. If once the running threads decreases to lower count than it's not increased.

Comment: @NahumLitvin, I have thousands file to process. So I need mechanism to process them on multiple fix threads.

Comment: use regular System.Threading.Thread. X8 simple producer consumer

anyway C# knows better than you how many threads to use. it will use all 8 threads if it is ideal.

Comment: @Romil Having thousands of items to process is in no way a reason to need exactly 8 threads no matter what.  The framework will have no problem running optimally under such circumstances.

Comment: You have to realize that you are doing this *drastically* wrong.  Using threads on a single disk drive is exceedingly bad for perf.  It just has a single reader head, it does *not* like to be commandeered around by multiple threads.  Head seeks are by far the most expensive thing a drive can ever do.  Only use a *single* thread to read from the disk, you can use as many threads as you want to actually process the data that was read.  A thread-safe queue is the usual approach, standard single-producer, multiple-consumer problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
OrderablePartitioner<Tuple<int, int>> chunkPart = Partitioner.Create(0, fileList.Count, 1);//Partition the list in chunk of 1 entry

ParallelOptions opt= new ParallelOptions();
opt.TaskScheduler = null;
opt.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8;

Parallel.ForEach(chunkPart, opt, chunkRange =>
{
    for (int i = chunkRange.Item1; i < chunkRange.Item2; i++)
    {
        DoSomething(fileList[i].FullName);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a producer / consumer model. Create one producer and 8 consumers. For example:

```
BlockingCollection<string> _filesToProcess = new BlockingCollection<string>();

// start 8 tasks to do the processing
List<Task> _consumers = new List<Task>();

for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
{
    var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(ProcessFiles, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    _consumers.Add(t);
}

// Populate the queue
foreach (var filename in filelist)
{
    _filesToProcess.Add(filename);
}

// Mark the collection as complete for adding
_filesToProcess.CompleteAdding();

// wait for consumers to finish
Task.WaitAll(_consumers.ToArray(), Timeout.Infinite);
```

Your processing method removes things from the `BlockingCollection` and processes them:

```
void ProcessFiles()
{
    foreach (var filename in _filesToProcess.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        // do something with the file name
    }
}
```

That will keep 8 threads running until the collection is empty. Assuming, of course, you have 8 cores on which to run the threads. If you have fewer available cores, then there will be a lot of context switching, which will cost you.

See [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

Comment: This is simply deferring 8 concurrent actions to the thread pool.  The thread pool is entirely within its rights to use any number of threads to process those requests.

Comment: @Servy: True enough. My experience, though, is that the `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` typically causes the thread pool to treat it as a dedicated thread. That said, it's easy enough to convert this to use managed threads (i.e. `Thread` class).

Comment: +1 Thanks Jim, I was looking for exact this.
I know that running fixed 8 threads is not a good solution. Only my motive was to know the design to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Within a static counter, you might be able to get the number of current threads.
Every time you call start a task there is the possibility to use the Task.ContinueWith (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696.aspx) to notify that it's over and you can start another one.
This way there is going to be always 8 tasks running.

Comment: This is simply deferring 8 concurrent actions to the thread pool.  The thread pool is entirely within its rights to use any number of threads to process those requests.